# iOS: Change NSMutableAttributedString's Font Height Without Changing Font Width?

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, nsstring, nsmutableattributedstring

I have an NSMutableAttributedString "timeString" whom's font and color I have already set. Everything is working fine, but I was wondering if there were a way to alter the text's height without changing the text's width (font width = 100%, font height = 120%).

I tried using transform, but it's not available for NSMutableAttributedStrings. Thanks!

Comment: How are you displaying this string? If it's in a UILabel, you can use a transform on it.

Comment: I'm drawing it over an image to create a new image: [timeString drawInRect:rect];

Comment: while you drawing over image you can alter rect, change rect height will help you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to apply transforms to a string as a string is not actually a UI element. Your best bet in this case is to either add the Attributed String to a UILabel, transform the label's height and then draw the label in your context. Or transform whatever context you are drawing the text into.